# JQ Grid, Sorting does not work as expected

Tags: jquery, sorting, jqgrid

I have a grid that is supposed to be sorted on the click of a column header. Certain columns such as ID sort well as expected but certain columns such as date when clicked, although sends request to the server and sorts but the rows are not well sorted. I have included a picture to depict this scenario [image: sort]
From the picture, the time column does not sort as expected, the last row there should come earlier than it is when sorted (JAN 24 before 28)...

Here's my server side code..

```
//Get the requested page
$page = $_GET['page'];

//Get how many rows we want to have into the grid
$limit = $_GET['rows'];

// get index row - i.e. user click to sort. At first time sortname parameter -
// after that the index from colModel 
$sidx = $_GET['sidx']; 

// sorting order - at first time sortorder 
$sord = $_GET['sord']; 

// if we not pass at first time index use the first column for the index or what you want
if(!$sidx) $sidx =1;

//array to translate the search type
$ops = array(
    'eq'=>'=', //equal
    'ne'=>'<>',//not equal
    'lt'=>'<', //less than
    'le'=>'<=',//less than or equal
    'gt'=>'>', //greater than
    'ge'=>'>=',//greater than or equal
    'bw'=>'LIKE', //begins with
    'bn'=>'NOT LIKE', //doesn't begin with
    'in'=>'LIKE', //is in
    'ni'=>'NOT LIKE', //is not in
    'ew'=>'LIKE', //ends with
    'en'=>'NOT LIKE', //doesn't end with
    'cn'=>'LIKE', // contains
    'nc'=>'NOT LIKE'  //doesn't contain
);
function getWhereClause($col, $oper, $val){
    global $ops;
    if($oper == 'bw' || $oper == 'bn') $val .= '%';
    if($oper == 'ew' || $oper == 'en' ) $val = '%'.$val;
    if($oper == 'cn' || $oper == 'nc' || $oper == 'in' || $oper == 'ni') $val = '%'.$val.'%';
    return " WHERE $col {$ops[$oper]} '$val' ";
}

$where = ""; //if there is no search request sent by jqgrid, $where should be empty
$searchField = isset($_GET['searchField']) ? $_GET['searchField'] : false;
$searchOper = isset($_GET['searchOper']) ? $_GET['searchOper']: false;
$searchString = isset($_GET['searchString']) ? $_GET['searchString'] : false;
if ($_GET['_search'] == 'true') {
    $where = getWhereClause($searchField,$searchOper,$searchString);
}

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

// calculate the number of rows for the query. We need this for paging the result 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM renal_accessLog"); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC); 
$count = $row['count']; 

// calculate the total pages for the query 
if( $count > 0 && $limit > 0) { 
              $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit); 
} else { 
              $total_pages = 0; 
} 

// if for some reasons the requested page is greater than the total 
// set the requested page to total page 
if ($page > $total_pages) $page=$total_pages;

// calculate the starting position of the rows 
$start = $limit*$page - $limit;

// if for some reasons start position is negative set it to 0 
// typical case is that the user type 0 for the requested page 
if($start <0) $start = 0; 

// the actual query for the grid data 
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM renal_accessLog ".$where." ORDER BY $sidx $sord LIMIT $start , $limit"; 
$result = mysql_query( $SQL ) or die("Couldn't execute query.".mysql_error()); 


 $responce = new stdClass();
$responce->page = $page;
$responce->total = $total_pages;
$responce->records = $count;
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $responce->rows[$i]['id']=$row['id'];
```

Here's my client side code

```
 $(function () {
            $("#list").jqGrid({
                url:"grid_accessLog.php",
                datatype: "json",
                mtype: "GET",
        colNames:["ID","Ip Address","User Info","Time","Page","Referrer","Search","User Agent","Notes"],
                colModel: [
            { name: "id",index:"id", width: 55,search:true},
            { name: "ip_address",index:"ip_address",search:true, width: 90 },
            { name: "user_info",index:"user_info",search:true, width: 100},
            { name: "time",index:"time",search:true,sorttype:"text", width: 90},
            { name: "page",index:"page",search:true, width: 120},
            { name: "referrer",index:"referrer",search:true, width: 90 },
            { name: "search",index:"search",search:true, width: 90 },
            { name: "user_agent",index:"user_agent",search:true, width: 120 },
        { name: "notes",index:"notes",search:true, width: 120 }
        ],

         pager: "#pager",
            rowNum: 30,
            rowList: [10,20,30],
            autowidth:true,
            sortname: "id",
            sortorder: "desc",
            viewrecords: true,
            autoencode: true,
            caption: "Access Log",
            height: 'auto'

                            }).navGrid("#pager", {search:true, edit:false,add:false,del:false,searchtext:"Search"});
                                             });//end ready
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your code mentioned Default sorcolumn is **id**.
Change `sortname: "id"` to `sortname: "time"`

Comment: I have tried this option before but still the problem persists. Thanks for your input.